# Build project with aot in Angular

Tags: angular-cli

I got problem with build when I use `[somvar]` and input the object like `{a:value}`.

I type `ng build --prod --aot`.

**error Msg**

```
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("mTemplate", [ngOutletContext]='{ item: item, dropdown: dropdown, index: i, disable: !selectable[i] }[ERROR ->]')
```

**my.pug**

```
ng-template([ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate", [ngOutletContext]='{ item: item, dropdown: dropdown, index: i, disable: !selectable[i] }')
```

Instead of useing `{...:...}`,I fixed the `[ngOutletContext]` to `[ngOutletContext.item]`.It would display like

**code**

```
ng-template([ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate", [ngOutletContext.item]='item',[ngOutletContext. dropdown]="dropdown",[ngOutletContext.index]="i",[ngOutletContext.disable]="!selectable[i]")
```

it works well but it's too complex to set `ngOutletContext`.Is any simple thing to deal it?

**added**

**tsconfig.aot.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/app/ay.module.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,I found my fault in `pug`.

If the project only got the pure resolver that `template-language` can't pass AOT compile.

What we need to do is translate to html then got `AOT` compile, regardless..

Big risk after webpack, parse `pug` to `html` every single compiled.Hope the `pug-resolver` plugin it's supported to `AOT` nor compile would be slowly if we need to `aot`.